# how to set IF statments for a costume taxonomy post list?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, bookmarks

i have this array code to list bookmark links in "link-category" taxonomy.

```
    <?php
    function wp_list_bookmarks_cm($args = ''){$defaults = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC','limit' => -1, 'category' => '', 'exclude_category' => '','category_name' => '', 'hide_invisible' => 1,'show_updated' => 0, 'echo' => 1, 'categorize' => 1, 'title_li' => __('Bookmarks'),'title_before' => '<h2>', 'title_after' => '</h2>', 'category_orderby' => 'name', 'category_order' => 'ASC','class' => 'linkcat', 'category_before' => '<li id="%id" class="%class" >', 'category_after' => '</li>' );$r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );$output = '';if ( ! is_array( $r['class'] ) ) {$r['class'] = explode( ' ', $r['class'] );}$r['class'] = array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $r['class'] );$r['class'] = trim( join( ' ', $r['class'] ) );if ( $r['categorize'] ) {$cats = get_terms( 'link_category', array('name__like' => $r['category_name'],'include' => $r['category'],'exclude' => $r['exclude_category'],'orderby' => $r['category_orderby'],'order' => $r['category_order'], 'hierarchical' => 0) );if ( empty( $cats ) ) {$r['categorize'] = false;}}if ( $r['categorize'] ) {foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {$params = array_merge( $r, array( 'category' => $cat->term_id ) ); $bookmarks = get_bookmarks( $params );if ( empty( $bookmarks ) ) {continue;}$output .= str_replace(array( '%id', '%class' ),array( "linkcat-$cat->term_id", $r['class'] ),$r['category_before']);$catname = apply_filters( 'link_category', $cat->name );$output .= $r['title_before'];$output .= $catname;$output .= $r['title_after'];$output .= "\n\t<ul id='ci$cat->term_id' class='xoxo blogroll' style='height:530px;'>\n";$output .= _walk_bookmarks( $bookmarks, $r );$output .= "\n\t</ul><div class='animated bounceInRight holder holder$cat->term_id'></div>\n";$output .= $r['category_after'] . "\n";}} else {$bookmarks = get_bookmarks( $r );if ( ! empty( $bookmarks ) ) {if ( ! empty( $r['title_li'] ) ) {$output .= str_replace(array( '%id', '%class' ),array( "linkcat-" . $r['category'], $r['class'] ),$r['category_before']);$output .= $r['title_before'];$output .= $r['title_li'];$output .= $r['title_after'];$output .= "\n\t<ul id='ci$cat->term_id' class='xoxo blogroll'>\n";$output .= _walk_bookmarks( $bookmarks, $r );$output .= "\n\t</ul><div class='animated bounceInUp holder holder$cat->term_id'></div>\n";$output .= $r['category_after'] . "\n";} else {$output .= _walk_bookmarks( $bookmarks, $r );}}}$html = apply_filters( 'wp_list_bookmarks', $output );if ( ! $r['echo'] ) {return $html;}echo $html;}?><?php get_header(); ?><div class="container">
     <div class="linkspageL"><div role="alert" class="load_links animated bounceInDown col-md-12 note note-sc alert-dismissable fade in" style="margin:60px 10px 60px 10px;font-size:13px;cursor:wait;"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;پیوند ها در حال بارگزاری است لطفا صبر کنید ...<br></div>
       <div class="linksrow links">
        <div class="links-c1"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2588&orderby=title&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
        <div class="links-c2"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2467&orderby=title&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
       <div class="links-c1"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2589&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
         <div class="links-c2"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2590&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-building" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
        <div class="links-c1"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2591&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
       <div class="links-c2"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2592&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
        <div class="links-c1"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2593&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
      <div class="links-c2"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2594&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
         <div class="links-c1"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2595&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>
       <div class="links-c2"><?php wp_list_bookmarks_cm('category=2596&orderby=ID&order=ASC&limit=-1&title_before=<h2><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> &title_after=</h2>');?></div>

               </div></div></div><?php get_footer(); ?>
```

now i want to set if statement to each bookmark  link that have "hott" tag.

i used this but not working:

```
 'category_before' => '<li id="%id" class="%class" <?php if ( is_tax('link_category','hott' ) ) {?> style="color: #ff8c00;" <?php } ?>
  >', 'category_after' => '</li>'
```

what i can do now?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do this easily. Bookmarks don't use Walkers, so you can't add a custom Walker extending the default.

You can't use the ternary operator ("condition ? then : else"), because it will be interpreted before being passed into the function, thus only be evaluated once, not for every item.

You'll have to get the bookmarks and build the ouput yourself. You'd probably be able to copy a lot of the code from `_walk_bookmarks()` in `/wp-includes/bookmark-template.php`

Comment: i'm not a professional in code. can u give more description?  i updated question code. i have a costume function to list bookmarks. please check up

Comment: You will have to replace `wp_list_bookmarks_cm` with a function you wrote yourself. That function would have to work with a custom function replacing _walk_bookmarks() as well, because that's where you'll need to change the code.

Comment: this function?  `function _walk_bookmarks( $bookmarks, $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'show_updated' => 0, 'show_description' => 0,
        'show_images' => 1, 'show_name' => 0,
        'before' => '<li>', 'after' => '</li>', 'between' => "\n",
        'show_rating' => 0, 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => ''
    );      `

Comment: Yes, but I was wrong. You should be fine just replacing wp_list_bookmarks, as I suppose you've already done with wp_list_bookmarks_cm. Search for `category_before` in that function and adjust the code.

Comment: i adjust the  `category_before`  to  `'category_before' => '<li id="%id" class="%class" <?php if ( is_tax('link_category','hott' ) ) {?> style="color: #ff8c00;" <?php } ?> >'`  but it return error.   i need to  change item color if taxonomy is "hott" .   `is_tax` is used for archive pages.